# Wait(&status) system call in linux

Tags: c, linux

I am doing this program in linux and I cant understand the output of the program with wait(&val) system call

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int val = 5;
    if (fork())
        wait(&val);
    val++;
    printf("%d\n", val);
    return val;
}
```

```
huzee98@ubuntu:~$ ./task2a 
6 
1537
```

Comment: Insert the code here (not an image).

Comment: Is it really easier to take a screenshot, upload it to a hosting and place link here than just copy and paste it as text?

Comment: Now is really the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Spoiler: What's `((5 + 1) << 8) + 1`?

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to [read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)? What does it tell you?

Comment: I have read several topic on wait() system call and what I am not understading is the "1537" as output. What is the role of return statement in this code snippet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the child, your program simply adds 1 to 5, producing 6, prints 6, and then returns 6 as its exit status.

In the parent, after `wait(&val)` returns successfully, `val` contains a [magic cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_cookie).  The exit status of the child is encoded in this cookie, but it must be extracted using the macros `WIFEXITED`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WTERMSIG`, etc.  Incrementing the cookie numerically does not make sense. Printing it out numerically produces something that you *can* interpret mentally if you know how the W-macros work on your particular operating system, but you shouldn't do that except to debug something.

The number that the parent printed in your program, 1537, is easier to understand in hexadecimal: 0x0601.  That means the original cookie value, before you incremented it, was 0x0600. On Linux, `WIFEXITED(0x0600)` is true, and `WEXITSTATUS(0x0600) == 6`.  On any other operating system it might or might not mean the same thing.

Assuming that your intention was to produce a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) for printing 6 and then 7, a better way to do that would be like this:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
   int val, status;
   pid_t pid = fork();
   if (pid == -1) {
       perror("fork");
       return 1;
   }
   if (pid == 0) {
       val = 5;
       val++;
       printf("%d\n", val);
       return val;
   }
   /* we are the parent if we get here */
   if (wait(&status) != pid) {
       perror("wait");
       return 1;
   }
   if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
       assert(WIFSIGNALED(status));
       printf("child process killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
       return 1;
   }
   val = WEXITSTATUS(status);
   val++;
   printf("%d\n", val);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: your answer is very helpful. but can you please explain briefly why the program displays 1537 as the output in the question asked above

Comment: @HuzaifaJalil I just added a sentence about that.

Comment: @HuzaifaJalil Please reread this answer, what I said earlier about 1537 was wrong.

Comment: and what is 1281 meaning

Comment: @HuzaifaJalil It means you changed your program so the child returns 5 instead of 6 but you didn't change anything else.  You should already have enough information to know how I figured that out.

Comment: yeah It was from another code snippters and the program did not increment the value and runs exit(var) command that is why 1281 is diplayed